# Assistance in recognizing & visualizing a specific topology

Tags: geometric-topology, visualization

I’m a bit out of my element asking math questions here, but hopeful someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Questions:

1. Do the two tables illustrated below each form a shape in math-topology?  I’m thinking they both form a torus shape; some sort of “lumpy-torus” shape?
2. How would one go about graphically visualizing these table-shapes?  Can anyone provide a little direction to a specific software/tool that would allow me to create a computer visual?

[image: Table A and Table B]

Comment: The image you have linked show a bunch of powers of symbols named $a$ and $b$. Is it possible you are pointing to the wrong thing?

Comment: That's the correct image - 'Table A' and 'Table B', represented as different powers.  It's possible my question may be complete hogwash, but I thought these tables could help define a topology for someone with that kind of background.

Comment: What does it mean for a table to "form a shape in math-topology"? Do you know what a topology is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To reach something like what you're talking about, the most straightforward interpretation I can think of is to proceed along the following steps:

1. Treat each table as a group homomorphism from $\mathbb Z^2$ to an infinite cyclic group generated by $\sqrt a$ or $\sqrt b$.
2. Let $K$ be the kernel of this map; so on the left side, $K_a=\langle(1,1)\rangle$ and on the right side, $K_b=\langle(5,3)\rangle$.
3. Since $\mathbb Z^2$ embeds in the $2$-dimensional Lie group $\mathbb R^2$, each of $K_a$ and $K_b$ is automatically a (closed) subgroup of $\mathbb R^2$, so we can form the quotient group $\mathbb R^2/K_a$ or $\mathbb R^2/K_b$, which is another $2$-dimensional manifold with a different topology.

In that case, the result is a cylinder, not a torus. Ideally one would like to draw the original $\mathbb Z^2$ grid on this cylinder; I'm not aware of software that would do that. You could do it on actual paper, though; cut, rolled into a tube, and glued back together.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I’ll have to consult my friend to help digest this response, but I appreciate it.  I’m starting to realize my question may have been nonsensical. I have more homework todo.